# How should I change the Lens type variabl when using Hugin from Command line

Tags: shell, hugin

I am currently trying to use Hugin from Command line to load images and stitch them together. Following the steps shows here: http://wiki.panotools.org/Panorama_scripting_in_a_nutshell

Now, I want to add some information about Lens type and Focal length from the command line but I could not find any source telling me how to do that. (Theoretically, I should be able to use all the functions that in the GUI Hugin version by using the command line. )

This is how the GUI version looks like, and you can see the tab for changing lens type and space for inputting focal length:
[image: gui version of Hugin]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by modifying the *.pto file directly.
by the command **pto_gen**, you could import images into our project and a pto file will be generated from that. And you could find the parameters for each images in your project in the *.pto file.
I changed the **Lens type** and **Focal length** parameters for each images by modifying the *.pto file directly. (read *.pto, modify the **f** value for some image(s), and save the changes.)